# What does the prefixes mean in UNIX NETWORK PROGRAMMING?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

When I was reading the book *Unix Network Programming*, there are many socket apis/types having prefixes like `sin_addr` with `sin`, `inet_addr` with `inet`, and `in_addr_t` with `in`. What do those prefiexes actually mean, that is, what are the full names?

Comment: They're not just in the book, they're in the Berkeley Sockets API. Something like `sin_addr:` Socket Internet address, i.e. including a port number; `inet_addr:` Internet address; `in_addr_t:` Internet address.

Comment: @EJP Thanks a lot. How do you know their full names? By guessing, or are there documents/naming idioms about these API?

Comment: By inference from context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the very early days structure members had to be unique. Using the same name for a member in two different structures failed. This is still (and always was) true for assembly macros that help use C structs and preprocessor macros.

The structures and constants from the old days therefor use a prefix that is usually derived from the structure name or context. E.g. struct addressinfo uses a prefix of ai, struct sockaddr uses sa, struct sockaddr_in uses sin and so on.

Using unique names for each member allows using the same name for C and asm code, which made reading and writing code in both languages easier. No need to mentally switch tracks when switching language.

Comment: "Using the same name for a member in two different structures failed" - any reference or is it just your speculation?

Comment: Just a vague memory and certainly before ansi C. The use of the same name in ASM file is probably more significant.

Comment: See for example [this old C manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf), at the end of section 8.5: `However, names of tags and members must be distinct. The same member name can appear in different structures only if the two members are of the same type and if their origin with respect to their structure is the same; thus separate structures can share a common initial segment.`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley No kidding(?!).  When was this published?  It looks like the late 70s.

Comment: @ErikBennett check out the rest of https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/ for historical context (it says that manual is from V6 unix, May 1975)

Comment: of course this doesn't really prove that such a restriction still existed when the BSD people were inventing sockets, but it's a pretty good theory.

Comment: These are quite fascinating for people like me who wrote hello world in 21st century.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley This restriction didn't exists no more at the time IP stack was implemented (as I can remember) but habits may have a very long life (and maybe some old compilers where in use at some places).I can remember that in the middle 80's we used old K&R function declarations and no prototyping.

Comment: Didn't gcc still have K&R compatibility after the turn of the millennium? Old habits do die hard. And don't forget, asm macros still have the restriction even today.